# Partial upload on S3 using pre-signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm going to partially upload a file, on S3 using pre-signed URLs. My problem is not about the 5GB limit of the S3. Actually, my files are about 100MB.

But the problem is that I want to break the file into chunks and upload each part separately, to handle failed "part uploads" better and give a better experience to the client user.

So I'm looking for a way like how we download a file partially, using the byte-range headers. I know that there is no "byte-range" like header for the `PUT` method :(

I also can't use S3 SDK directly into my clients and I'm forced to use pre-signed URLs. I have a service that generates the pre-signed URLs using go SDK and then all of the other works are done by the clients using the URLs.

I'm also wandered is it right to upload a 100mb file ( or even smaller ) partially? Why the AWS and others didn't consider this option to upload partially with one pre-signed URL?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? Did you look into presigned post url?

Comment: @ZobayerHasan I couldn't solve the problem with pre-signed urls, so I forced to make a service to do the partial upload itself. It generates some custom urls for the client and uploads each part with S3 SDK.